# Prolog; a question about notation in an assignment

Tags: prolog, computer-science

I get hat isa/2 is a rule, that takes two objects or terms. But what would isa2/2 imply? That isa is defined twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isa2/2` simply refers to a predicate named `isa2` taking 2 arguments, i.e. the first 2 is simply part of the name, not a special notation.